# Error While sending the mail in xpages

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

i am facing one issue in xpages,

i am able to sent a mail in lotus notes client sucessfully, but in xpages i am getting following error.

i alredy checked the server document also. it all with
Please help.

***Code Used : in button click() ssjs ***

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();  
doc.replaceItemValue("form", "Memo");
doc.replaceItemValue("sendTo", "tuser1@gmail.com");
doc.replaceItemValue("subject", "an email to you");
var RT:NotesRichTextItem=doc.createRichTextItem("Body")
RT.appendText("This is my Text")
RT.addNewLine()
doc.send();
```

i am getting following error.

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=10, col=5: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send() null
```

**Stack Trace :**

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:102)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:126)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=10, col=5: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.send()
null
    com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDomino$fct_Document.call(WrapperDomino.java:9683)
    com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
NotesException: Notes error: The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.
    lotus.domino.local.Document.send(Unknown Source)
    lotus.domino.local.Document.send(Unknown Source)
    com.ibm.xsp.script.WrapperDomino$fct_Document.call(WrapperDomino.java:9586)
    com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:362)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    com.ibm.xsp.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:60)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:324)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIEventHandler.broadcast(UIEventHandler.java:366)
    com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.broadcast(UIViewRootEx.java:1535)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:307)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:428)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:96)
    com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.execute(FacesControllerImpl.java:256)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:228)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:350)
    com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:306)
    com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Please Help.. i tried most of the solutions .. but none of them is worked out..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a bug in `document.send()` implementation.

According to [the documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Document_send.html) try to call `send()` with a recipient parameter.

in your code, instead of `doc.send();` call `doc.send("tuser1@gmail.com");`.

If it still does not work, try every available `send` method for this class, described by the link I provided above.

Comment: Try to implement this functionality without using xpages, for instance - using a form with lotusscript/java agent. To embed this form to your xpage consider iframe approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the following which might be causing the problem?

1. Is the server actually able (configured correctly) to send the message?
2. Do you have access (in the ACL) to create documents in the database?

Comment: i am having Manager access...  all mail are working perfectly in Client but its not working in web.

Comment: Can you confirm if the server is configured correctly to actually send mail?

Comment: i check in server document ... its all configured correctly..can u please tell me which setting i need to verify in the server document

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_8.5.3/com.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc/H_ENABLING_SMTP_ROUTING_STEPS.html - Also have a look at the outgoing mailbox, both locally on your machine and on the server to see if any emails are there - They will also give a failure reason if there are any

Comment: I'm not sure, my admin knowledge is minimal... Did you check the outgoing mailbox's to see if there were any unsent documents?

Comment: I just dropped a button on a blank xpage, copied your code exactly, only changing the email address to my own, and it works fine, so your code isn't the issue